# Writing to a file not working after publishing AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, filestream

I have this very weird problem. I have a procedure for logging in my AIR application. When i run it in the Flash CS5.5 i can open the log file successfully and modify it. When i publish the application (tried swf, exe and OS-X app) with AIR 2.6 the application freezes the first time i try to access the log file. The code i use is the following:

```
public function log(action:String)
{
    var file:File ;
    var time:Date ;
    var time_str:String ;

    time = new Date();
    time_str = time.getFullYear()+"-"+(time.getMonth()+1)+"-"+time.getDate();
    try {
    file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath( "IdeasMappingData/" +time_str + "_" + "log.txt" );

    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()

        stream.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);

        time_str += "\t"+time.getHours()+":"+time.getMinutes();

        trace(time_str+"\t"+action);
        stream.writeUTFBytes(time_str+"\t"+action+"\n");
        stream.close();
    } catch (error:IOError) {
        trace("The stream could not be accessed for logging.");
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code, are you sure that the problem is withing this function and not somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
file = new File( File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath( "IdeasMappingData/" +time_str + "_" + "log.txt" ).nativePath ) ;
```

Intsead of

```
file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath( "IdeasMappingData/" +time_str + "_" + "log.txt" );
```

Air have sometime strange security approach when you use resolvePath directly